# Reg Exp que verifique que la primera y ultima letra de un string sean vocales y a demas que sean la misma vocal

Tags: regex, match

estaba haciendo un regExp con la condicion del titulo:
Palabra que empiece y termine en vocal y ambas sean la misma, tengo este regExp:

```
    let re = new RegExp('^[aeiou]*?=$[aeiou]');
```

Las letras entre la primera y ultima (si es que hay) no importa que sean consonantes.

No funciona, no se que se me puede estar escapando, este string **`abcda`** no lo acepta y si deberia de ser valido...

Comment: Tu expresión regular no funcionará por varias razones, entre ellas la más importante es que el signo `=` que has usado no sirve para forzar la igualdad, como pareces pensar, sino que busca que exista literalmente un signo `=` dentro de la palabra. También tienes mal el poner el `$` "en medio", ya que representa el final de la línea, y por tanto siempre debería ir al final. Para hacer referencia a algo aparecido previamente debes usar un grupo de captura (paréntesis) y un `\1` que será el valor capturado por ese grupo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quizá haya una solución más elegante pero puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular:

`^([aeiou])[a-z]*\1$`

Lo que hace esta expresión regular es capturar con `([aeiou])` un grupo que luego se pasa como referencia en `\1`

Comment: Sólo por completar un poco esta respuesta: Usando "named groups" se puede hacer lo mismo con esta expresión regular equivalente: `(?<vocal>[aeiou])[a-z]+\k<vocal>`

Answer (score 0):

Esta expresion espero pueda servir

```
/^(?<first>[aeiou])[a-zA-Z]*(\k<first>)$/
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).